# Inexplicable "Invalid Argument" error from fopen_s

Tags: c, fopen, errno

In essence I have come across an issue while working on a project to send files over a socket. I'm a bit of a newbie, and after a few hours of searching I still haven't found a working solution, but I have boiled down the problem into the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    const char* fileName = "‪C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\bugs.jpg";

    FILE* f;
    fopen_s(&f, fileName, "r");
    
    if (f == NULL)
        printf("Null Result");
    else
        printf("Working");

    printf("\nError %d \n", errno);
}
```

For some reason the program is unable to open the file, and errno returns a value of 22, which corresponds to **EINVAL**, or invalid argument [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/errno-doserrno-sys-errlist-and-sys-nerr?view=msvc-160). I am very confused as it appears that I am providing fopen_s with the correct arguments according to its specification. Any help or pointers(haha) is greatly appriciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems unlikely that your user name is in fact `"Username"`

Comment: The actual username is my real name, and as such chose to change it for the post, as its value is unrelated to the main question :)

Comment: My guess is that the path is wrong written or that the file is not really there

Comment: maybe you are using cygwin? or something like that, try with a relative path => just to make sure you find something

Comment: Perhaps it's only in the question, but copy/pasting your code gives me a warning `warning C4566: character represented by universal-character-name '\u202A' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)` and retyping the filename fixes it as well as opening the file correctly. You want `"rb"` if you're opening a binary file.

Comment: The file is certainly there, but the path format could be incorrect, can you suggest how the path might be formatted differently?

Comment: This is a C program, not a C++ program. C++ doesn't have `fopen_s`. C does. Also, shouldn't you check the return value (the `errno_t`) from `fopen_s`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, `fopen_s` is available in C++ as part of Microsoft's `stdio.h`. As for the returned error, `fopen_s` also sets the global error level, accessed thru the `errno` global as in the code above.

Comment: @JonathanLidbeck I guess it's available as an extension in MSVC via the C++ header `cstdio` (that often includes `stdio.h`)  but I consider the program as written to be a C program nevertheless. It even includes a resource leak that one wouldn't get if the C++ class `std::ifstream` had been used instead.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the comments I found out why it wasn't working. Essentially, I was copying the "Object Name" field from the file properties to save time typing it out. Somehow this drags along an invisible '\u202A' character which completely breaks fopen_s.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTCmX.png)

In a nutshell, don't try and cut corners.